# Simulation of a truncated normal distribution over two intervals

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, simulation, truncation, truncated-normal-distribution

Given $X$ a random variable with a normal distribution, what is the best procedure to simulate $X|X\in[a;b]\cup[c;d]$, i.e. we want to simulate the truncated normal distribution only on the intervals $[a;b]$ or $[c;d]$.

I have already seen a question asked on this forum in [Truncated normal distribution over a union of intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/221689/213710.), but the answer gives no indication of how to simulate a sample of this law.

Comment: I am astonished by your claim that the answer "gives no indication of how to sample," because it *includes working code!*  Please take another look.  However, that code implements the (potentially lethally inefficient) rejection method.  Instead, just invert the CDF.  Alternatively, sample from a mixture of two Normals, each truncated on one of the intervals.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming wlog that the truncated Normal is a standard $\mathcal N(0,1)$ Normal, the density of the distribution to be simulated writes as
$$f(x)\propto e^{-x^2/2}\mathbb I_{(a,b)}(x)+e^{-x^2/2}\mathbb I_{(c,d)}(x)$$
or, with the normalising constant
$$f(x)= \dfrac{e^{-x^2/2}\mathbb I_{(a,b)}(x)+e^{-x^2/2}\mathbb I_{(c,d)}(x)}{\sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)+\Phi(d)-\Phi(c)]}$$
when assuming that $a<b<c<d$. As noted by [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber), this writes as a mixture of two truncated Normal distributions,
$$f(x)= \dfrac{\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)}{\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)+\Phi(d)-\Phi(c)}\dfrac{e^{-x^2/2}\mathbb I_{(a,b)}(x)}{\sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)]}\\
\qquad\qquad\qquad+\dfrac{\Phi(d)-\Phi(c)}{\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)+\Phi(d)-\Phi(c)}\dfrac{e^{-x^2/2}\mathbb I_{(c,d)}(x)}{\sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(d)-\Phi(c)]}$$
Since the probability weights
$$\dfrac{\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)}{\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)+\Phi(d)-\Phi(c)}\quad\text{and}\quad\dfrac{\Phi(d)-\Phi(c)}{\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)+\Phi(d)-\Phi(c)}$$
are available, one can pick a component (first or second) according to its probability and then simulate the corresponding truncated Normal (for which I once [wrote](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4010) an [efficient accept-reject algorithm](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00143942) that has been implemented in an [R package](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/msm/html/tnorm.html)).

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I don't think you need to do anything more sophisticated than simulating from an unconstrained Normal distribution, and then exclude values outside of your intervals (example in R):

```r
mu = 0
sigma = 1
low1 = -1
high1 = -.5
low2 = 0
high2 = 1
x = rnorm(n, mu, sigma)
in_interval = (x > low1 & x < high1) | (x > low2 & x < high2)
trunc_x = x[in_interval]
```

There are also [more efficient, but more complicated solutions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12843/generating-random-samples-from-a-custom-distribution), that let you sample directly from an arbitrary distribution.

Comment: This can be *incredibly* inefficient.  Try it with a standard Normal distribution truncated to $(-10,-6)\cup(6,10),$ for instance.