# Valid highly informative prior for proportion

Tags: distributions, bayesian, prior, beta-distribution

I am trying to find a prior distribution for a proportion $\theta$ that is highly informative i.e. it is almost point mass at $\theta$ but I am not able to find such distribution that is valid for a proportion. I could use easily a normal distribution with really small variance but our professor said that it would be incorrect because the support is the whole $\mathbb{R}$ and $\theta\in [0,1]$.Thus, I restricted my self to beta distributions but I cannot find a point mass beta distribution.

So I would like some help in order to find such distribution even if it's not a beta distribution.

Comment: What's wrong with the beta distribution?  You can make it as concentrated as you want around a single value, e.g., a Beta(1000,1000) has a mean of 0.5 and a standard deviation of 0.011.

Comment: @jbowman you are completely right!Thank you.

Comment: You can also use truncated normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted in comments, you can use [beta distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution/47782#47782) with high values of parameters. If that's easier, you can [re-parametrize beta distribution in terms of location and scale](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/316086/distribution-that-has-a-range-from-0-to-1-and-with-peak-between-them/316088#316088). But you can also use normal distribution, Laplace distribution, or whatever distribution you want but with [truncating it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219384/truncated-gaussian-distribution-interpretation/219401#219401) into $(0, 1)$ interval.